# Trying to convert a string/char to an integer yielded an unexpected result

Tags: c++

I came across something strange. It is probably trivial but I can't find the answer. Can anyone explain to me why in this action I get a result of 49?

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;
    string binary = "10101011";

    number = int(binary[0]);
    cout << number; // result is 49 , why is that?    
}
```

Comment: The character `'1'` has a numeric value of `49` in the ASCII character set.   Although there are different character sets, ASCII or a related character set are used more often than not.   Incidentally, there is no standardised character set in which the character `'1'` has a numeric value of `1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`binary[0]` is `'1'`, which has an ASCII value of 49.

Comment: Ok, so it's return ASCII value. What is a simplest way to change it from string "1" to int 1 ? I tried: number = stoi(binary[0]); but it return an error.

Comment: It yields an error, because binary[0] is a char, not a string. try `stoi("1")` or `stoi(binary)`

Comment: You can either use `atoi(*char)` or
`binary[0]-'0'` - this basically subtracts ASCII of '0' with the ASCII of the character 'binary[0]'. The result is an integer.

Comment: @AdityaNagesh `atoi` has the disadvantage that you cannot distinguish error from valid input `"0"`, so it only can be used if `"0"` is not acceptable input on application level, otherwise the function is not recommendable. Be aware, too, that subtracting `'0'` only is portable for digits of base 10 or less. Such operations on letters (e. g. determining case or converting to a different one) can fail as there are character sets where the letters are not arranged contiguously (most famous one being EBCDIC).

Comment: number = std::stoi(binary, nullptr, 2); for one bit number = binary[0]=='1';

Answer (score 1):

Because when you're trying to convert `binary[0]` element, which is of `char` type to `int` type - it converts char's ASCII code that is simply a number, as it was mentioned by @QuentinUK.

If you want to store bits and convert them to numbers, you should look at [std::bitset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

If you want to get any element out of `std::string` as a number, you should look at [std::atoi](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi).

Answer (score 0):

You have defined **string** binary = "10101011";
binary[0] is character '1'. When you parse a character to int, the output is ASCII value of the character.

Answer (score 0):

So actually in your code you are not printing that char in int but rather than you are printing ASCII value of `'1'` that is 49.

Whenever a char is converted to int it changes and assigns ASCII value of that char.

to solve your problem you can use folow:

```
#define conv_digit(ch) (ch-'0')
```

Then just call this function passing `binary[0]` or whatever char you want.